# How can I programmatically read what version of software I am using?

Tags: visual-studio, versioning

How can I programmatically read what version of software I am using?

If I use Visual Studio to create a project, and that project includes a resource (.rc) file and the version is specified in that file, how can I use code to "read" the version information?

That is, if I want the software to report what version it is when it is run, and the only place this information is stored is in the `.rc` file, what can I do?

Comment: @p.cambell Microsoft Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [GetFileVersion()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468915(v=VS.85).aspx) and related functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetFileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647003(VS.85).aspx) with the name of the current executable/dll to read the version information, which was embedded into the exe/dll when it was built from the resource file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using [VERSIONINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058(v=VS.85).aspx) in your resource files, use [these functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646981(v=VS.85).aspx).